# e.preventDefault(); stopping form from submitting when valid using Stripe's jquery.payment

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, stripe-payments, preventdefault

I'm using Stripe's jQuery plugin to validate credit card entry fields before details are being sent off for server side validation, but using Stripe's example my form will not submit, even when credit card data is valid.

The server side validation catches any issues, but I'd like to give users isntant feedback if there's an error in their data before it goes off to the server.

Stripe's jQuery plugin: https://stripe.com/blog/jquery-payment.
Their example: http://stripe.github.io/jquery.payment/example/

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4 and jQuery 1.11.2

My Form:

```
  <form novalidate autocomplete="on" name="securepay" id="securepay" method="post" action="?func=validate" data-toggle="validator">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="cc-number" class="control-label">Card Number:</label>
        <input id="cc-number" name="cc-number" type="tel" class="form-control cc-number paymentInput" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" data-error="Please enter the long card number" value="" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="cc-exp" class="control-label">Expiry Date:</label>
        <input id="cc-exp" name="cc-exp" type="tel" class="form-control cc-exp paymentInput" autocomplete="cc-exp" placeholder="MM / YY" data-error="Please enter the expiry date shown on the card" value="" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="cc-cvc" class="control-label">CVC Number:</label>
        <input id="cc-cvc" name="cc-cvc" type="tel" class="form-control cc-cvc paymentInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="•••" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="right" title="CVC Security Number" data-content="On most cards, the 3-digit security code is on the back, to the right of the signature. On American Express cards, the 4-digit security code is on the front, to the top-right of the card number." data-error="Please enter the CVC number" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="cc-name" class="control-label">Name on Card:</label>
        <input id="cc-name" name="cc-name" type="text" class="form-control cc-name paymentInput" autocomplete="cc-name" data-error="Please enter your name as specified on the card" value="" required>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
     <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cc-terms" required><span class="text-info small">Please confirm that you agree to our Terms and Conditions</span>
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <button type="submit" id="secure-submit" class="btn btn-primary margin-10">Make Payment</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: 'body'})

    //Form Validation
    $('#securepay').validator()

    //$('[data-text]').payment('restrictText');
    $('.cc-number').payment('formatCardNumber');
    $('.cc-exp').payment('formatCardExpiry');
    $('.cc-cvc').payment('formatCardCVC');

    $.fn.toggleInputError = function(erred) {
        this.parent('.form-group').toggleClass('has-error', erred);
        this.parent('button').toggleClass('disabled', erred);
        return this;
    };

    $('form').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var cardType = $.payment.cardType($('.cc-number').val());
        $('.cc-number').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardNumber($('.cc-number').val()));
        $('.cc-exp').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal')));
        $('.cc-cvc').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), cardType));
        $('.cc-brand').val(cardType);

    });
});
```

The problem is it uses `e.preventDefault();` which causes the form to not submit, even if the validation passes.

I'd like to use `preventDefault();` to stop the form from being submitted if there's an error, but what would be the best way implament it so that the form will submit when the validation passes? I'd tried a few different options, but I just don't seem to be able to get it to work the way I want it to.

Comment: What if you remove the submit type of the button and do the validation inside the onclick, and if it passes use .submit();

Answer (score 0):

at the end of your function you can add

```
$(this).unbind('submit').submit()
```

if the validation passed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am a little late, but perhaps it can be useful to someone..

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var cardType = $.payment.cardType($('.cc-number').val());
    $('.cc-number').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardNumber($('.cc-number').val()));
    $('.cc-exp').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardExpiry($('.cc-exp').payment('cardExpiryVal')));
    $('.cc-cvc').toggleInputError(!$.payment.validateCardCVC($('.cc-cvc').val(), cardType));
    $('.cc-brand').val(cardType);

    //check if there are errors
    if(!$('.has-error').length) {
      // The answare of @loli
      $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    }
});
```